# Recurive Backtracking: Leet Code - Remove Boxes (Python)

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

I was working on this leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-boxes/ and my answer is only slightly off for certain test cases. Any advice would be appreciated.

The problem is outlined as the following:

> You are given several boxes with different colors represented by different positive numbers.

> You may experience several rounds to remove boxes until there is no box left. Each time you can choose some continuous boxes with the same color (i.e., composed of k boxes, k >= >1), remove them and get k * k points.

> Return the maximum points you can get.

Example 1:

```
Input: boxes = [1]
Output: 1 => (1*1)
```

Example 2:

```
Input: boxes = [1,1,1]
Output: 9 => (3*3)
```

Example 3:

```
Input: boxes = [1,3,2,2,2,3,4,3,1]
Output: 23
Explanation:
[1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1] 
----> [1, 3, 3, 4, 3, 1] (3*3=9 points) 
----> [1, 3, 3, 3, 1] (1*1=1 points) 
----> [1, 1] (3*3=9 points) 
----> [] (2*2=4 points)
```

I decided to use recursive backtracking to try and solve this, and my code is the following:

```
from copy import deepcopy as copy
class Solution: 
    # Main function
    def backtrack(self, boxes, score, seen={}):
        # Make list hashable
        hashable = tuple(boxes)
        
        if len(boxes) == 0:
            return score
        
        if hashable in seen:
            return seen[hashable]
        
        pos_scores = []
        
        loop_start = 0
        loop_end = len(boxes)
        
        while(loop_start < loop_end):
            # keep original boxes for original 
            box_copy = copy(boxes)
            
            # Returns the continous from starting point
            seq_start, seq_end = self.find_seq(box_copy, loop_start)
            
            # Return the box array without the seqence, and the score from removal
            new_boxes, new_score = self.remove_sequence(box_copy, seq_start, seq_end)
            
            # Backtrack based off the new box list and new score
            pos_scores.append(self.backtrack(box_copy, score+new_score, seen))
            
            # Next iteration will use a fresh copy of the boxes
            loop_start = seq_end
            
        seen[hashable] = max(pos_scores)
        return seen[hashable]
        
    def remove_sequence(self, boxes, start, end):
        rem_counter = 0

        for i in range(start, end):
            boxes.pop(i - rem_counter)
            rem_counter += 1

        dist = (end - start)
        score = dist * dist
        return boxes, score
    
    def find_seq(self, boxes, start):
        color = boxes[start]
        end = start

        for i in range(start, len(boxes)):
            if boxes[i] == color:
                end += 1
            else:
                break

        return start, end
    
    def removeBoxes(self, boxes) -> int:
        return self.backtrack(boxes, 0, {})
```

My issue is that my code has worked for smaller examples, but is slightly off for the larger ones. I believe my code is *almost* there, but I think I'm missing an edge case. Any tips would be greatly appreciated. For example, I get the correct answer for [1,1,2,1,2] as well as most test cases. However my answer for the third example is 21, not 23.

Comment: Unfortunately, your approach of storing `seen` scores indexed by a remaining sequence is flawed, since different paths associated with different scores can lead to the same remains - e. g. the remaining sequence [1, 1] in the third example can be reached with score 17 as well as with score 19, and your code is hashing the sub-maximal 17.

Comment: Thank you! All I needed was to add `hashable = tuple(boxes), score`

Comment: @Armali, if you post this as an answer I will accept it!

Comment: Since I only pointed out a flaw in your code and you yourself found a solution, I suggest that you post your solution as a self-answer, which is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @Armali's comment, the solution to the code above is to use

```
        hashable = tuple(boxes), score
```